# Parse CEST/CET time in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have these date strings:

```
Fri Oct  7 16:00:09 CEST 2011
```

I want to convert them to UTC. I have tried with this implementation:

```
def LocalToUtc(localtime):
    return datetime.strptime(localtime, "%a %m %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y").isoformat() + 'Z'
```

But I get a `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: time data 'Fri Oct  7 16:00:09 CEST 2011' does not match format '%a %m %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [parsedatetime](http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/) library.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

1. You're using "%m" instead of "%b"
2. The standard lib can't parse "CEST", it understands only very few time zone names.
   See also here: [What possible values does datetime.strptime() accept for %Z?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302701/what-possible-values-does-datetime-strptime-accept-for-z)