# How to convert string date with timezone to datetime?

Tags: python, date

I have date in string:

```
Tue Oct 04 2016 12:13:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

and I use (according to https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
datetime.strptime(datetime_string, '%a %b %m %Y %H:%M:%S %z %Z')
```

but I get error:

```
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%a %b %m %Y %H:%M:%S %z %Z'
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992459/parse-cest-cet-time-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert string with UTC offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160143/how-to-convert-string-with-utc-offset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python datetime can't parse the `GMT` part (You might want to specify it manually in your format). You can use `dateutil` instead:

```
In [16]: s = 'Tue Oct 04 2016 12:13:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)'

In [17]: from dateutil import parser

In [18]: parser.parse(s)
Out[18]: d = datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 4, 12, 13, tzinfo=tzoffset(u'CEST', -7200))
In [30]: d.utcoffset()
Out[30]: datetime.timedelta(-1, 79200)

In [31]: d.tzname()
Out[31]: 'CEST'
```

Answer (score 5):

%z is the `+0200`, `%Z` is `CEST`. Therefore:

```
>>> s = "Tue Oct 04 2016 12:13:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
>>> datetime.strptime(s, '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z (%Z)')
datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 4, 12, 13, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 7200), 'CEST'))
```

I also replaced your `%m` with `%d`; `%m` is the month, numerically, so in your case `04` would be parsed as April.

Comment: Getting OP's error with Python 2.7, it works with Python 3.5. Do you know why?

Comment: Weird. I don't understand why, seeing as the documentation OP linked to is for Python 2..

Comment: `datetime.timezone` is apparently [only available in Python 3.2+](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types). If you're stuck with Python 2, `dateutil` might be the better choice.

Comment: That's because `%Z` only recognises a limited number of codes, and that does not include `CEST`.

Comment: Whoa, Python 2.7 documentation seems to claim a feature it doesn't have.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160143/how-to-convert-string-with-utc-offset

Comment: @Efferalgan No, `%Z` recognizes CEST, the problem is with `%z`. You can see that by taking away the `%z` part in both format and string and replacing `CEST` with e.g. `FOOBAR`.

Comment: @L3viathan I tried removing only `%Z` and it worked fine, whereas removing only `%z` did not change anything. I guess online interpreters are not that reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler way to achieve this without taking care of `datetime` formatting identifiers will be the usage of [`dateutil.parser()`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parser.html). For example:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser 
>>> date_string = 'Tue Oct 04 2016 12:13:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)'
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(date_string)
datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 4, 12, 13, tzinfo=tzoffset(u'CEST', -7200))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse all you `datetime` data in a column in pandas DataFrame, you can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method to apply together with `dateutil.parser.parse` to parse whole column:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].apply(parse)
```