# Python2.5 parse timestamp strings containing timeszones

Tags: python

I am trying to parse timestamp strings containing timezone information. When I execute the following on Python 2.5

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("20120805-18:30:00 EST", "%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S %Z")
```

I get:

```
ValueError: time data did not match format:  data=20120805-18:30:00 EST  fmt=%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S %Z
```

However I change "EST" to "JST" the line executes fine (working on a Japan server). Also one more thing I noticed was time.tzname returns a list with only 'JST'.

Is there a way to be able to parse all the usual timezones?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302701/what-possible-values-does-datetime-strptime-accept-for-z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to employ http://pytz.sourceforge.net/ for this. Standard `datetime` doesn't know EST/PST.